# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest returning null response in error scenario

Tags: ios, ios6, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

When i send a async request using the sendAsynchronousRequest method, it returns the null response in the error scenario like 'invalid username'. In the API, i am sending the response, at error scenario with corresponding JSON values.

It receives the JSON, but url response is null.

It works fine when i do this in connectionWithRequest: method with proper delegate methods.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                             NSLog(@"%@", (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response);
                                         }];
```

Comment: did you print response status code?

Comment: print both responsecode as response.statuscode and print [error localizedDescription]

Comment: @NHS - Response status code is 0 and error description is "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"

Comment: But received the data which contains the expected JSON.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

Straight from the documentation of said method:

> If the request fails, the data parameter is `nil` and the error parameter contain information about the failure.

Comment: I mentioned 'error scenario' in the sense like 'invalid username' not like 'request fails due to server error or offline, etc'. i received the data(which contains the information(JSON) about the errors like 'errormessage') and NSError too. So i thought, the request get success, but the url response prints as 'null'.